# Bring your custom Activity get launched at in fixed time duration

Tags: android

I want to keep my `activity` on TOP always.

I need to get my `Activity` called to TOP in every 5 sec.( not re-create).
I used `Timer`, but not able to do so.

Please help me.
If possible provide some code also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of forcing an opening of an `Activity`. It will get uninstalled from my phone and reported in the market :).

To do that you will need to use [BroadCastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

The idea is to set an alarm with the `AlarmManager` and when it's fired your `BroadCastReceiver` will use `context.startActivity();` to start your `Activity`.

Don't forget to make your `BroadCastReceiver` listen for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`. This way you can bother the user after the booting finishes :)

Comment: I think this will restart the app each time. But you can use basically this same idea and store a flag in some persistant storage (Preferences?) That you set to true in onStart() and false is onStop() then check it and only call startActivity if its false. I agree with macarse though, I hope this is not an app to be distributed on the market to average users.